# .ply (polygon) format file issue in ios 14

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, metal, ply-file-format

My app generates ply files after scanning objects. After ios 14 update the color of my 3d models does not load correctly. Also I am unable to view ply files in xcode (works fine in preview).

Anyone know the workaround to this problem?

I tired reading ply file content and display vertices and faces in scene geometry but it takes too long to load a file.

Apparently creating mdlAsset() throws some Metal warning and the mesh color does not show up properly.

Here are the sample images from ios 13 and 14 preview in sceneKit.

[image: comparison of ios 13 and ios 14 ply file preview in scenekit]

Comment: Can you quote the warning?

Comment: [Metal Compiler Warning] Warning: Compilation succeeded with: 

program_source:95:26: warning: unused function 'reduce_op'
    static inline float4 reduce_op(float4 d0, float4 d1)
                         ^
program_source:581:26: warning: unused variable 'scn_shadow_sampler_ord_z'
static constexpr sampler scn_shadow_sampler_ord_z = sampler(coord::normalized, filter::linear, mip_filter::none, address::clamp_to_edge, compare_func::greater_equal);

Comment: Checkout this thread https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659856

Comment: @SaadTahir did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @D.Rothschild I have not find any solution to this problem yet. Even reading the PLY file abd making a pointcloud is not a feasible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

same problem,i found it is a SceneKit's bug, i had a solution that read .ply file with C, and creat a SCNGeometry instance with data, main code:

1. first we need read vertexCount and faceCount in .ply file (my file is ASCII format,so, )

```
    bool readFaceAndVertexCount(char* filePath, int *vertexCount, int *faceCount);
```

example:

```
    bool readFaceAndVertexCount(char* filePath, int *vertexCount, int *faceCount) {
    
    char data[100];
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen(filePath,"r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("error!");
        return false;
    }
    
    while (!feof(fp))
        
    {
        fgets(data,1024,fp);  
        unsigned long i = strlen(data);
        data[i - 1] = '\0';
        
        if (strstr(data, "element vertex") != NULL) {
            char *res = strtok(data," ");
            while (res != NULL) {
                res = strtok(NULL, " ");
                if (res != NULL) {
                    *vertexCount = atoi(res);
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (strstr(data, "element face") != NULL) {
            char *res = strtok(data," ");
            while (res != NULL) {
                res = strtok(NULL, " ");
                if (res != NULL) {
                    *faceCount = atoi(res);
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        if (*faceCount > 0 && *vertexCount > 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    return  true;
}
```

2, read data to array:
in .c

```
// you need to implement with your files
bool readPlyFile(char* filePath, const int vertexCount, int faceCount, float *vertex, float *color, int *elment)
```

in .swift:

```
 var vertex: [Float] = Array.init(repeating: 0, count: Int(vertexCount) * 3)
        
 var color: [Float] = Array.init(repeating: 0, count: Int(vertexCount) * 3)
        
 var face: [Int32] = Array.init(repeating: 0, count: Int(faceCount) * 3)
        
 readPlyFile(UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutating: url.path),vertexCount,faceCount,&vertex,&color,&face)
```

3 creat a custom SCNGeometry:

```
       let positionData = NSData.init(bytes: vertex, length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * vertex.count)
        
        let vertexSource = SCNGeometrySource.init(data: positionData as Data, semantic: .vertex, vectorCount: Int(vertexCount), usesFloatComponents: true, componentsPerVector: 3, bytesPerComponent: MemoryLayout<Float>.size, dataOffset: 0, dataStride: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 3)
        
        let colorData = NSData.init(bytes: color, length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * color.count)
        
        let colorSource = SCNGeometrySource.init(data: colorData as Data, semantic: .color, vectorCount: Int(vertexCount), usesFloatComponents: true, componentsPerVector: 3, bytesPerComponent: MemoryLayout<Float>.size, dataOffset: 0, dataStride: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 3)
        
        
        let indexData = NSData(bytes: face, length: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size * face.count)
        
        let element = SCNGeometryElement(data: indexData as Data, primitiveType: SCNGeometryPrimitiveType.triangles, primitiveCount: Int(faceCount), bytesPerIndex: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
        
        let gemetry = SCNGeometry.init(sources: [vertexSource,colorSource], elements: [element])
        
        let node = SCNNode.init(geometry: gemetry)
        
        let scene = SCNScene.init()
       
        node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.cullMode = .back
        node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
        scnView.scene = scene
```

it work! and faster!